# Como centralizar uma imagem usando bootstrap na NavBar do bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

estou com uma grande duvida no bootstrap, criei uma Navbar usando as classes bootstrap padrão.... o problema é que não consigo centralizar um logo no centro da navbar,funciona apenas o posicionamento de esquerda para direita....gostaria de uma solução que seja padrão do bootstrap,o código está assim.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">


<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo-3.svg" width="50px">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Centralizar em relação à navbar/tela ou em relação ao espaço que sobrou devido ao button (no caso, mais pra esquerda da tela)?

Comment: No caso seria centralizar na navbar/tela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para centralizar em relação à tela, use o `css` a seguir:

```
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px; /*opcional*/
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado  Jhonatan !

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Se a resposta está de acordo com o que você precisava não esqueça de aceitá-la como correta. Abraço!